# Pulling data into customer websites

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I was wondering if anyone would be able to offer some suggestions as to the best way to implement the following:

We are looking to offer some stand alone code that any client regardless of platform should be able to build into their website, the code needs to draw down information from our site and display it on the customers.

At the moment I am developing this solution in jquery to pull down the html/css and then simply filling a div with the resulting content, the idea being all a customer would need to do is add a div with the correct name and pull in our javascript?

Is there a "better" way to do this type of thing or am I going down the right road?

Comment: You need to clarify "draw down" and "pull in", what content are you trying to present and so on?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that approach imho. The other option would be iframes, but I prefer your solution. Unless you hit dreaded cross domain content errors.

Comment: Sorry we are trying to display job adverts relating to that client, essentially when they post adverts on our site we also want them to appear on their own automatically

Comment: Thanks Jeff, yeah I was going to use JSONP to get round the browser same origin policy enforced by many.

Comment: dangerous trying to insert jQuery to another site. Can cause all sorts of conflicts. Shouldn't need jsonp if provide data in script, assuming data is static after page load

Comment: This would be a fine solution, I think. Some companies that offer APIs, like Authorize.net, offer it in a number of server side languages so you can pick whichever works for you. The common fb and twitter APIs are just JavaScript, though, and work similarly to what youve described. and that seems to work just dandy!

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, surely if we do "if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){" then and only then load ours up it'll be fine no?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a dynamic html page, write a small customizable iframe script and provide it to your clients.

**Your site**
`http://ads.your-site.com/client-name` displays the list of ads for this specific client

**Client site**
`<iframe src="http://ads.your-site.com/client-name"></iframe>` embeds that list on the clients website.

Of course you can make it more fancy with jQuery and ajax requests and all that.

Comment: As I understand it that can stick up a big yes/no box about allowing frames to navigate across domains though right?

Comment: The other problem with iframes is that we need to pass parameters to the script since each customer will have different records to display...

Comment: If you prefer JSONP, i just found this [snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/68583/jsonp-public-api-with-jquery-getjson-callback-mysql/). Maybe it can be of use.